# How can i map the data from controller in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

in create page view ,

I have a radio button like this,

```
<%=radio_button_tag(:repeat, "1")%><%=f.label("None")%>
<%=radio_button_tag(:repeat, "2")%><%=f.label("Start Now")%>
<%=radio_button_tag(:repeat, "3")%><%=f.label("Daily")%>
<%=radio_button_tag(:repeat, "4")%><%=f.label("Weekly")%>
<%=radio_button_tag(:repeat, "5")%><%=f.label("Monthly")%>
```

and if i submit, it sends like this.

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"jJP/GZxllRLV2q/gENb0raCVhKPlASPdc+f6hqP23dE=", "appointment"
=>{"appointmentname"=>"test for repeat daily first", "description"=>"daily "}, "repeat"=>"3", "start_date"=>"20
14-03-13", "start_time"=>"16:00", "end_time"=>"17:00", "repeat_time"=>"19", "roomType"=>"1", "bb_state_id"=>"10
7", "jNameTimeZone"=>"Etc/GMT", "invited_radio_btn"=>"1", "numberOfParticipants"=>"1", "moderatorId"=>"1", "att
endee_list"=>[{"id"=>"1", "email"=>"hyunjae.park@access-company.com", "firstname"=>"hyunjae", "lastname"=>"park
"}]}
```

as you can see, the parameter `"repeat"=>"3"` is there.

ok, i saved this to the database.

now, i want to edit this page.

from the controller it sends the param like this.

```
@repeat
```

If i print this with logger.debug. it shows what i have chosen(1~5 value)

now, with this parameter

in the view, i have to map the radio_button which has been chosen when the room was created.

But it doesn't matches it :(

What is my problem in here???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
<%= form_for @post do |f| %>
  <%= f.collection_radio_buttons :repeat, [[1, 'none'], [2, 'start now']], :id %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

within the form
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html#method-i-collection_radio_buttons

or without a form:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_radio_buttons